Using control button to extract worksheet from workbook and save as separate file
I'm currently working out of a workbook that has 5 separate tabs.  All five tabs pull from one feeder worksheet.  Once feeder worksheet is populated, I need to extract one of the tabs and save it as a separate file while still maintaining the link to the feeder worksheet in the original document.  I'd extraction to save the worksheet as the original file name plus the worksheet tab name.  Overall, I'd like to have a control button on the feeder worksheet that will run the VBA Macro and extract the worksheet.
I've tried multiple steps, but nothing worked.
I can get it extract the appropriate sheet by just recording the macro
Sub Remove_Test_Analysis()
'
' Remove_Test_Analysis Macro
'

'
    Sheets("CSF Test Analysis").Select
    Sheets("CSF Test Analysis").Move
    Windows("CSF 24-19.xlsm").Activate
End Sub

But I need it to be dynamic enough across multiple different name workbooks as well automatically save the new file as the previous file name + the extracted worksheet name.

Always helps to include what you tried, along with a description of what happened when you tried it.  Post asking for a solution but without any code tend to get closed here.
